# Calculate Time Difference for Date/Time Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have two variables 'triage_date_time' and 'checkin_date_time'. Both are formatted  as, for example, 2018-12-31 14:13:00. Showing the year-month-day and hour-minute-second both within one cell.

I wanted to create a variable that calculates the time it takes from check-in to  triage.

I attempted to use the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT datediff(minute, 'triage_date_time', 'checkin_date_time') as 
checkin_to_triage
```

However, when running this code I get the following error... "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

Any suggestions of how I can write a code that would calculate the minute difference of these two variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is obviously the single quotes.  Assuming that you are using SQL Server, variables start with `@`.  So:

```
select datediff(minute, @triage_date_time, @checkin_date_time) as checkin_to_triage
```

If you are confused and really mean columns in a table, then:

```
select datediff(minute, triage_date_time, checkin_date_time) as checkin_to_triage
from t;
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, there are no single quotes in the variable name, I was just quoting them to discern their full name, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

could it be that your field is a CHARACTER  data type ? 
cast your char to datetime

```
SELECT DISTINCT datediff(minute, CAST(triage_date_time AS datetime), CAST(checkin_date_time AS datetime)) as checkin_to_triage
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query

```
DECLARE @triage_date_time DATETIME = '20181231 14:13:00' 
DECLARE @checkin_date_time DATETIME = '20181231 16:13:00'  

SELECT DATEDIFF (MINUTE, @triage_date_time, @checkin_date_time) AS 'checkin_to_triage'
```

Output :

### checkin_to_triage

120